# "wrong first argument" exception in Process.spawn

Tags: ruby, windows

I'm trying to spawn a process like this

```
# name I get from network (I'm using webrick)
Process.spawn(name)
```

however I end up with

```
ArgumentError: wrong first argument
```

But it's a bit weird. When I use `binding.pry` to break right before the
`Process.spawn` call, this is what I get:

```
> name
=> "notepad.exe"
> name == "notepad.exe"
=> true
> Process.spawn(name)
ArgumentError: wrong first argument
from (pry):23: in `spawn`
> Process.spawn("notepad.exe")
=> 728
> Process.spawn(name.to_s)
=> 1416
```

So I just verified that `name` is equal to `"notepad.exe"` and `Process.spawn`
fails when called with `name` and succeeds when called with `"notepad.exe"`. It
also works when called with `name.to_s`. Could someone explain me what is going
on?

Both `name` and `"notepad.exe"` have `UTF-8` encoding (verified via `name.encoding`) and neither `name` or `name.to_s` is `tainted?`.

I looked at [source code](https://github.com/ruby/ruby/blob/1e84c8343f38aab16299ddfb7cb20d3e9dabba6f/process.c#L1998)
but have no idea what's going on.

Comment: _"name I get from network"_ – what do you mean by that? Is `name` actually a string or just something that looks or acts like a string? What does `name.class` return? What about `name.singleton_class.ancestors`?

Comment: `WEBrick::HTTPUtils::FormData`, however that's a subclass of `String` so it should work? Unless I'm missing something fundamental about OOP, I always thought that subclass can be use instead of base class

Comment: You're referring to the Liskov substitution principle – the L in [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)). Seems like `FormData` violates it. I don't really know, why it is a subclass of `String`. That doesn't seem to make much sense (and apparently causes trouble and confusion).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem was that `WEBrick::HTTPUtils::FormData` defines `#to_ary`. So I'll just work around that with `name.to_s`.